# mouseover only on path in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg, mouseevent, mouseover

I have a radar chart with polygons. Now I want them to be filled with color on mouseover, but only when the mouse is on the path. When the mouse is inside the polygon it should have no fill.

So far I tried

```
svg.selectAll('.polygon')
    .data(scaledData)
    .enter()
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', radialLine)
    .attr('stroke', function(d, i) {return colors(i);})
    .attr('stroke-width', '3')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.select(this).attr('stroke')).attr('opacity', 0.3);
    })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "none").attr('opacity', 1);
    });
```

Which fills when I'm over the whole polygon. Also I'd like to have the stroke stay the same and not change it's opacity.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Set the attribute `pointer-events="visibleStroke"` to trigger the event over the stroke, and use `fill-opacity` instead of `opacity`.

```
svg.selectAll('.polygon')
    .data(scaledData)
    .enter()
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', radialLine)
    .attr('stroke', function(d, i) {return colors(i);})
    .attr('stroke-width', '3')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'visibleStroke')
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.select(this).attr('stroke'))
          .attr('fill-opacity', 0.3);
    })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "none")
          .attr('fill-opacity', 1);
    });
```

Comment: Think you were talking about
d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.select(this).attr('stroke'))
this part, but only with this I get the right color for the polygons.

But still it stays filled,  even when I'm on the interior of the polygon

Comment: I have seen that only after 3 hours of poking around: it is actually `pointer-events`, not `pointer-event`. Argh.